# Where are j5create USB to HDMI drivers saved?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hdmi, driver, peripheral

Does anyone know where I could find the j5create USB to HDMI drivers that I just downloaded, or where they saved? I've searched but I can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 1):

I checked hd/library/extensions and found them. I've included a screenshot, the mct drivers are the drivers in question.
[image: mctdrivers]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. I'm glad you resolved your issue! :) However, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info such as the full path (there are multiple _library_ folders in macOS) and also how you would access/view the folder (in the event it is hidden).